# Perl script which will do the Global interpolation of number and timestamps

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a perl script which will do the Global interpolation of number and timestamps (timestamps format `YYYYmmDDHHMMSS`, e.g. `20150124010502`) with system time. The format remain the same as in the original file and is reduced by one minute in each file.

The input files would be *file01.txt*, *file02.txt* , *file03.txt*, *file04.txt* and so on. All the file have the same number and timestamps and size.

```
4947000219, 20150124010502 ,2
```

In our output file we want to replace the existing number and timestamps. The number needs to increment and the timestamps should be replaced with system time and formated like in the original file.

Assuming the system time *“Mon Jan 19 13:39:57 IST 2015”* our replaced timestamps is `20150119133957` and the minute will be reduced by one minute in each file.
The output file should look like this:

```
file01.txt 4947000219, 20150119133957 ,2    
file02.txt 4947000220, 20150119133857 ,2    
file03.txt 4947000221, 20150119133757 ,2    
file04.txt 4947000222, 20150119133657 ,2    
file05.txt 4947000223, 20150119133557 ,2    
file06.txt 4947000224, 20150119133457 ,2    
file07.txt 4947000225, 20150119133357 ,2    
file07.txt 4947000226, 20150119133257 ,2  


.    
.    
.    
.
```

and so on.

Below is the perl script we created. But it's not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;    
use File::Find;
use Time::Local;      
use POSIX ();  

my $n;    
my @local=(localtime);

my $directory= "/home/Doc/Test";
chdir $directory;
opendir(DIR, ".") or die "couldn't open $directory: $!\n";

foreach my $file (readdir DIR){    
next unless -f $file;
  open my $in_fh, "<$file";
  my @lines = <$in_fh>; 
  close $in_fh;
  my $date = POSIX::strftime( '%Y%m%d%H%M%S', @local);
  ++$n;    
        $lines[0] =~ s~/(4947000219)/~$1+$n~ge;
        $lines[1] =~ s~/(20140924105028)/~$date-$n~ge;

    open my $out_fh, ">$file";
    print $out_fh @lines;    
    close $out_fh;   
}    
closedir DIR;
```

Can anyone tell me, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to subtract a integer from a date string to reduce the number of minutes:

```
$lines[1] =~ s~/(20140924105028)/~$date-$n~ge;
```

That won't work. Instead, substract 60 seconds from the `time` parameter given to `localtime` and use `strftime` again for every file.

Answer (score 0):

This started out as a comment but the limited code formatting possibilities made it an answer instead.

I am not sure i understand you correctly. Is there a number of input files in the same format as the output file? Because else i do not understand at all where you get the timestamp and number from. I will assume your input files look just like the output and you only want to change some numbers around. If that is not true, i still believe that my second point might help you out, the example however will not.
If i get your problem correctly, i would assume your problem are the `s~~~ge`.

First, you only replace a number in the first line and a timestamp in the second. It appears you lost a loop somewhere (there even is the indentation) and got confused about what `@lines` is. So first of all you need a loop over all your lines.

Second, from your example input it looks as if there are in fact no slashes. Your replacement however looks for a specific number in between slashes, removing those slashes in the process. I would assume the slashes are left overs from a matching operator you copied or something. But as your replacement operator uses `~` for separation, those slashes are literal.

Third you look for a specific number when the whole point of regular expressions is being better than search&replace.

If i am not mistaken, you look for something along the lines of

```
foreach my $currentLine (@lines) {
    ++$n;
    $currentLine =~ s~(\S*) (\d*), (\d*)~print "$1 ", $2+$n, ", ", $date-$n~ge;
    #any number of non-spaces# #any number of digits#, #any number of digits#
}
```

Comment: perl -p -i -e 's/(4947000219)/$1+1/ge' file01.txt  # i was able to increment number from this code where in script it's not working..here i'm searching specific number.

Comment: @michaelhuser Well, yes, in that string you use `s/old/new/ge` while in the script you try to use `s~old~new~ge` which would work just as well. But in your script you write actually `s~/old/~new~ge` and that means you actually look for `/old/` instead of just `old` to replace with `new`. That means it won't find anything unless you actually have slashes and actually want to replace them.